# Kubuntu login problem 2

Tags: kubuntu, login, versions

recently I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. that is something I know. then It started to update. after updated I could see now I have more versions of Linux like kubuntu. so excited i tried to log into kubuntu. but every time I entered my password it says its wrong. then I changed the version into Ubuntu and entered the password boom! it work!
now I need to know do they have default password to log into that version or is there anything else i do not know.  PS. I am a Newbie to Linux

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of Kubuntu you are running but, the user name should be ubuntu and you leave the password space blank. That should get it.